# ¿Cuál es la etimología de "chirona"?

Tags: etimología

[**Chirona**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8sZ7eQA) aparece en el DLE como

> 1. f. coloq. **cárcel** (‖ local de reclusión de presos). *Meter, estar en chirona.*

En el CORDE aparece por primera vez en 1799 (Luis Gutiérrez: Cornelia Bororquia. Historia verídica de la Judith española):

> Su ilustrísima me la ha metido en **chirona**, y me la tendrá alli hasta sabe Dios cuando.

Consultando el NTLLE veo que aparece por primera vez en el diccionario de Salvá (1846):

> f  fam. La cárcel

Sobre su etimología:

> - el DRAE de 1899 y el diccionario de Pagés de 1904 indican que proviene de *encerrona*
> - el DRAE de 1914 y el diccionario de Alemany y Bouffer (1917) ya no son tan categóricos: "**quizá** de *encerrona*"
> - los restantes diccionarios (anteriores y posteriores) accesibles por el NTLLE en que figura omiten cualquier indicación a su orígen.
> - [Etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?chirona) apunta a una relación con Gerona (en catalán Girona), que se pronunciaría más o menos como "yirona".
> - [Definiciona.com](https://definiciona.com/chirona/) indica que es de etimología incierta.

Queda pues la duda: ¿de dónde procede?

Answer (score 4):

Leyendo un artículo [El Estado, en busca del tiempo perdido](https://elpais.com/elpais/2018/12/15/opinion/1544898113_281176.html) de Juan Luis Cebrián di con este fragmento:

> “Lo de estar en chirona, metáfora de estar en la cárcel, procede de que en Gerona había una prisión muy famosa, como pudo serlo luego la de Carabanchel. Si te mandaban a Chirona (Girona en su defectuosa pronunciación) era que te enviaban a la cárcel”.

Se comenta en [el foro de CVC](https://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=43406):

> Por otra parte, parece posible que Gerona se hiciera famosa por albergar uno de los centros penitenciarios más frecuentados por los gitanos, prostitutas y otros detenidos en las calles, en virtud de la franquista «Ley de Vagos y Maleantes», de triste memoria

Interpretando lo escrito en el [Diccionario del origen de las palabras, entrada *chirona*](http://www.esacademic.com/dic.nsf/sp_sp_origen/134/chirona). Ahora bien, en esta página quitan peso a esta hipótesis porque dicha *Ley de Vagos y Maleantes* es de los años 1930 y la palabra ya se mencionaba en el siglo XVIII, como bien indica [Charlie en su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26357/1674).

Lo que se me ocurre es que puede que sea la [prisión militar de Figueras](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/tag/prision-militar-de-figueres/), en la provincia de Gerona, a la que se refieren y que se utilice *Chirona* por el [nombre aragonés de esta provincia](https://an.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provincia_de_Chirona). Siendo una prisión militar me parece factible que encaje por los tormentos que se describen en etimologías de Chile.

Answer (score 2):

Pues está la cosa complicada. No voy a poder dar una respuesta a tu pregunta pero no podía dejar de escribir lo poco que he encontrado.

En primer lugar, aclarar que, efectivamente, la expresión se registra por primera vez en 1799 en el CORDE. En la hemeroteca de la BNE no hay casos anteriores a ese.

El *Fichero General*, que suele ser mi último recurso, apenas contiene un par de fichas con comentarios interesantes. Una ficha afirma que la palabra viene de la germanía, aunque el diccionario no lo recoja así. La otra dice lo siguiente:

> El señor J. Corominas, a quien consideramos autoridad máxima en materia etimológica, dice que es palabra de origen desconocido y que no la ha encontrado "ni en los diccionarios portugueses o en vocabularios de andaluismos o americanismos". Ante tal incertidumbre nos atrevemos a preguntar: vendrá acaso de *chirinola* que en Cervantes es "junta de rufianes"?

No encuentro la definición mencionada para *chirinola* en el Diccionario de Autoridades, en todo caso. Una última ficha encuentro que afirma que *chirona* a veces significa "cama", y *meterse en chirona* sería pues "acostarse". Tampoco sé lo que tendrá esta afirmación de verdad.